# Can't run "rake test" after dropping a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In one of my recent migration files, I dropped a table I created a long time ago (drop_table :transactions)

Since then "rake test" fails with

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "transactions" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "transactions"
^
: DELETE FROM "transactions"
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `async_exec'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec_no_cache'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `block in exec_delete'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:670:in `exec_delete'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:101:in `delete'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:497:in `block (4 levels) in create_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:496:in `each'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:496:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:492:in `each'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:492:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:491:in `block in create_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:523:in `disable_referential_integrity'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in `create_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in `load_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in `setup_fixtures'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__291023375__setup__979454852__callbacks'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
```

I have no mention of transactions in my entire app (beside migration files).

It's working fine in dev and production environment, it's just the test that fails.

I tried rake db:test:prepare but it's already ran after a rake test. I dropped the test database before running my rake test, the database is re-created but same error happen.

Any idea where to look at/how fix it so I can run my tests again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is calling methods of `fixtures` creation.

Please check all your fixtures to check if there is no relation to `transation` model. With a grep, it will be OK

Comment: Bummer! I have an EMPTY file transactions.yml. Nothing in it... good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first verify the `transactions` table doesnt exists in all three db(`dev,pro,test`)
if this has been already done,you need to run `rake db:migrate` to **update** your `schema.rb`
.i believe `transactions` table is still there in `schema.rb` which too needs to be updated.

Comment: No it's not in my schema and it's not in the test database.